# Sonar error : Wrong source path use by the analyser

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I run the command below with GitLab CI / CD:

```
mvn  -s /etc/gitlab-runner/maven/settings-maven.xml --batch-mode test sonar:sonar
-Dsonar.java.source=1.8 
-Dsonar.host.url=${SONARHOST} 
-Dsonar.projectKey=${SONARKEY} 
-Dsonar.projectName=${SONARNAME} 
-Dsonar.projectVersion=${SONARVERSION} 
-Dsonar.sources=myproject_core/src/main/java,myproject_service/src/main/java,myproject_persistance/src/main/java 
-Dsonar.language=java 
-Dsonar.java.binaries=myproject_core/target/classes,myproject_service/target/classes,myproject_persistance/target/classes 
-Dsonar.java.libraries=**/*.jar 
-Dsonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco  
-Dsonar.surefire.reportPaths=myproject_core/target/surefire-reports,myproject_service/target/surefire-reports,myproject_persistance/target/surefire-reports 
-Dsonar.junit.reportPaths=myproject_core/target/surefire-reports,myproject_persistance/target/surefire-reports,myproject_service/target/surefire-reports 
-Dsonar.verbose=true 
-Dsonar.binaries=myproject_core/target/classes,myproject_service/target/classes,myproject_persistance/target/classes 
-Dsonar.jacoco.reportPaths=myproject_core/target/jacoco.exec,myproject_service/target/jacoco.exec,myproject_persistance/target/jacoco.exec 
-Dsonar.exclusions=**/*Test*/** 
-Dsonar.tests=myproject_core/src/test,myproject_service/src/test,myproject_persistance/src/test
```

So, I want to analyse 3 project **core**, **service** and **persistance** (I have 7 modules in my project)

**myproject-parent**

- myproject-core
- myproject-persistance
- myproject-service
- myproject- ...

But, I have this error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project myproject-parent: The directory '/builds/git-myproject/myproject-parent/**myproject_persistance/myproject_core**/src/main/java' does not exist for Maven module fr.xxx.xxx.myproject:myproject_persistance:jar:1.1. Please check the property sonar.sources -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project myproject-parent: The directory '/builds/git-myproject/myproject-parent/myproject_persistance/myproject_core/src/main/java' does not exist for Maven module fr.xxx.xxx.myproject:myproject_persistance:jar:1.1. Please check the property sonar.sources
```

On this sonarqube error, i can see that in the path, module **persistance** is include on module **core**, but this is not the case

I'm looking for why but I can't find. Have you ever had this problem ?

Comment: If you are using maven and use maven sonar plugin you don't need to provide these properties.

Comment: I don't use maven sonar plugin, so i pass all parameters in tne mvn commands. What can modify or replace the values of the properties ?

Comment: No, you are using maven to run sonar analysis. The command `mvn sonar:sonar` is maven sonar analysis using maven sonar plugin. Your error message states that clearly.

Comment: Thank you. So I changed the configuration to use maven-sonar-plugin and a dedicated profile. But the problem is still the same.

I think I found a lead: The job performs the sonar analysis for each module of the project and searches for sources from the root of the current project by adding the source declared in the profile.

Comment: In my example error, it is the persistence module that is analyzed and it concatenates the path of the module (/builds/git-myproject/myproject-parent/myproject_persistance) with the first source parameter of the sonar profile (myproject_core/src/main/java)

So, how can we tell maven to only analyze certain modules and how to indicate the associated sources?